# Android phonegap code to get the full path of certain directory from sdcard?

Tags: android

How can i get the full path of the folder which is in android sdcard?

Comment: My requirement is that i need to copy a image from my android device and paste on the folder in the sdcard, using android phonegap code. 

function onDeviceReady(){
getFileSystem();} 

function getFileSystem(){
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0,
    function(fileSystem){ 
        root = fileSystem.root;
        listDir(root);
}, function(evt){ 
        console.log("File System Error: "+evt.target.error.code);
    }
);
}

Using the above code i can access sdcard but i need to access a folder which is sdcard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the following string to get the full path of Folder:

```
String path=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                .toString() + File.separator +Folder_Name
```

Comment: my folder name is "app" in sdcard... if i used like this is it will work?
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

$("h1").click(function(){
 String path=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + File.separator +app;
 alert(path);